# Applet in index.html not loading with IIS. Works fine when index.html is opened with browser

Tags: java, iis, applet

I have a java applet which will load fine if I open the index.html file directly with a browser but fails to load when it is run with IIS 7.5, here is the code for the index.html

I get the feeling this is something to do with permissions in IIS, but since I am a bit of a noobe with IIS I have know idea how to use it properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">        
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: #000000; 
        color: #aaaaaa; 
        font-family: sans-serif; 
        text-align: center; 
        margin-top: 5em;
    }
    a:link {color: #F88113; text-decoration: none}
    a:visited {color: #ad5a0d; text-decoration: none}
    a:active {color: #F88113; text-decoration: none}
    a:hover {color: #F88113; text-decoration: underline}
    </style>
    <title>TitleScene</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="game">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
pulpcore_width = 1066;
pulpcore_height = 800;
pulpcore_archive = "TitleScene.jar";
pulpcore_assets = "TitleScene.zip";
pulpcore_scene = "TitleScene";
//--> 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="pulpcore.js"></script>
<noscript><p>To play, enable JavaScript from the Options or Preferences menu.</p></noscript>
</div>

<div id="source" style="margin: 5em auto 0 auto;">
    <a href="http://www.interactivepulp.com/pulpcore/">Powered by PulpCore</a>
    <blockquote style="margin-top: 5em; text-align: left">
        <div></div>
    </blockquote>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Emm... I am not pretty sure in IIS but if it was Tomcat I would advise you to

- A) Use common applet tags `<applet></applet>`
- B) ... or use JNLP applet launching way
- C) and refer to your applet jar as a net one as
  http://aHost:aPort/anappletpackage/TitleScene.jar

Report that helps

Good luck

Comment: Ok I used tomcat and tried everything you suggested, using <applet></applet> makes it not load, and referring to the applet jar as a web one didn't make any difference I have no tried using JNLP and I will probably just make some kind of build script that can be run off a flash drive since this is for a school project

Comment: Show here the steps you tried; its hard to analyze are they correct or not :(  does the applet get run in your IDE have you tested the app as a desktop app before applet adaptation? And one more thing... show the pulpcore.js script content

Comment: the applet is built using apache ant, which produces the index.html, pulpcore.js, play.gif, splash.gif, game.jar, game.zip. There is no way for it to run in the IDE because netbeans does not seem to have the feature anymore. The pulpcore.js file is too long to put here, but here is the deployment advice that I was following for pulpcore: [http://code.google.com/p/pulpcore/wiki/DeploymentAdvice]

Comment: First it is unclear how the div as <div id="game">
applet options are used next... How does the script takes options as pulpcore_width = 1066;
pulpcore_height = 800;
pulpcore_archive = "TitleScene.jar";
pulpcore_assets = "TitleScene.zip";
pulpcore_scene = "TitleScene";
etc so there are many dark edges which don't allow to analyze the error comes from :(

Comment: Just to test it... As a simplest way, I can advice you to use a simple html with no some outer js scripts links. The first thing you must check is A) where the applet is really located?; B) What paths the applet louncher uses to run it?; C) Are they identical?; So just check it first because it is the most common applet running error; Anyway, it's pretty hard to get where is the error comes from just seeing the html which is linked with an outer script with no in your question data as A) JNLP file itself ; B) applet running HTML; C) your applet stackTrace report; ...

Comment: ... so if after the said testing steps error keeps going please add the mentioned additional information into your question because it is important to see the project files configuration to say some more facts